# C#: How to check the value of the integer before a value?

Tags: c#

Let's say i have 2 strings of integers:

1,2,4,5,6 and 2,5,8

If both of the strings contain "5", I want to check the value of the integer before 5, then print. That means "4" and "2" will be printed.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far? Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: If both of my neighbors stub their toe at the same time I want a sandwich.

Comment: if @SamAxe gets a sandwich, i want a sand witch ! .

Comment: Why will it be "3" and "2" that are printed. Question not clear + show what you have tried.

Comment: And what should be printed if `5` is a first integer in a string?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
 for i = 1, i < stringSize, i++ 
   If string at i == 5 print string at i - 1 break
```

Real code:

```
using System;
namespace String{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bar('5',"12456","258");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void bar(char c, string strA, string strB)
    {
        if (Foo(c,strA)!= 'x' && Foo(c,strB)!= 'x')
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Foo(c,strA), Foo(c,strB)); 
        else  Console.WriteLine("no match"); 
    }

   static char Foo(char c, string str)
    {
        if (str[0].Equals(c)) return 'x';
        for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
            if (str[i].Equals(c)) return str[i-1];
        return 'x';
    }
}
```

}